# Double selection of a uitableviewcell in Custom Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i have an issue regarding UitableViewCell. the issue is that i have made a custom cell and i have a check box image button in that cell. i check and uncheck it. it works fine but the issue is that when i select Row # 1. it also selects row # 10 same goes with other rows like for 2 it will auto select row # 11. i am showing 10 rows at a time.

here is my code for CellForIndexPath

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
InterestsTableViewCell *cell = (InterestsTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell==nil) {
    NSArray *arrayNibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InterestsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [arrayNibs objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.total = [dataArray count];
}

cell.tag = indexPath.row;

cell.lblTitle.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (indexPath.row==0) {
    cell.imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCell_top_default.png"];
}else if(indexPath.row == [dataArray count]-1){
    cell.imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCell_bottom_default.png"];
}else{
    cell.imgBg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCell_middle_default.png"];
}

return cell;
```

Plus i am detecting touch so that i can change the background image (i have an other image as background). Code for Touch Began (in custom cell is below)

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
//NSLog(@"%i",tag);
isSelected = !isSelected;

btnTickMark.selected = !btnTickMark.selected;
(isSelected ?  (onImage = YES) : (onImage = NO));
```

Can somebody help me in this issue that why 2 rows are selected when i click a row.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because UITableView dequeues the cell. As you are showing 10 rows per screen it totally fits, that row 11 appears checked as it is dequeued from row 1.

To avoid that behavior you have to add a check to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to set your checked parameter for each cell – like the text you set for every cell.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of check, i dont understand

Comment: With "check" I mean an if-clause. I guess you store the checked or unchecked state of a cell somewhere, right? Maybe in the InterestsTableViewCell directly or in your dataArray. So like setting the text of the cell with "cell.lblTitle.text = [dataArray ..." you have to set the checked or unchecked state for every cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *arrayNibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InterestsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
for (id currentObject in arrayNibs){
    if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
        cell =  (InterestsTableViewCell *) currentObject;
        cell.Delegate = self;
        cell.total = [dataArray count];
        break;
    }
}
```

and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: i tried the provided solution but it did not helped at all. same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix - change this line from

```
InterestsTableViewCell *cell = (InterestsTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

to

```
InterestsTableViewCell *cell = nil;
```

Its not good from a memory/efficiency perspective because you won't be reusing the cells, instead will be reloading one from nib each time - but it will demonstrate whether what Florian Mielke is saying is correct (and his recommended approach will provide a better solution long term).

Comment: i did this way, now it wont select double cells but now the problem is that if i scroll the image is back to original i.e. unchecked image even if i have selected that cell. Can you please guide me more in this

Comment: Thanks for the help, its very good to know about the tip you gave, thanks